# jQuery Uniform iPad – doesn't click

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, uniform

I'm having trouble with the uniform plugin for jquery on iPads.

On an iPad if you go to http://shop.area51store.co.nz and go to "Mens" and click on a product you will notice that once it gets into this product detail view you are able to select a size. This doesn't seem to work when the iPad is in horizontal orientation but does work when it is in portrait. You tap it and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Update: Turns out I also can't edit the quantity when it's horizontal

Updated link:
http://www.shop.area51store.co.nz/estore/style/n5500565033.aspx

Comment: Still haven't been able to find an answer to this. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the :hover state and touch states.

Installing modernizr fixed this for me